# Getting data using Ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get the sub departments of the main department using Ajax in laravel in the same blade page : 
So in my controller i have make this code :

```
 public function check_parent(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        if($request->has('parent') && $request->input('parent') > 0)
        {
            $dep = DepartmentNews::where('parent','=',$request->input('parent'))->get();
           $data = view(app('admin').'.news.Deb_news.sub',['department'=>$dep,'parent'=>$request->input('parent')])->render();
            if(!empty($data))
            {
            return response()->json($data);
            }else{
            return response()->json('false');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And at the blade create for main Departments that will be the code :

```
  @if(count($department) > 0)
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).on('change','.checkparent',function(){


       var parent = $('option:selected',this).val();


                    if(parent == '' || parent == null )
                    {
                      $('.result').empty();
                    }else{

                      $.ajax({
                        url:'{{url(app('admin').'/department_news/check/parent')}}',
                        type:'post',
                        dataType:'json',
                        data:{parent:parent},
                        beforeSend: function()
                        {
                          $('.spin_dep').removeClass('hidden');
                        },success: function(data)
                        {
                          if(data != '')
                          {
                              $('.result').prepend(data);
                          }
                          $('.spin_dep').addClass('hidden');
                        },error: function()
                        {
                          $('.spin_dep').addClass('hidden');
                        }
                      }); 
                    }

              }); 
              </script>


 {!! Form::select('parent',$department,old('parent'),['class'=>'form-control checkparent','placeholder'=>'Select Main Department']) !!}
        @endif
<div class="result">

          </div>
            <p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x hidden spin_dep"></i></p>
                    </div>
```

and I have make also sub.blade  for getting the sub departments at the same page and here's it's code:

```
@if(count($department) > 0)

            {!! Form::select('parent',$department,old('parent'),['class'=>'form-control checkparent','placeholder'=>'Select Main Department']) !!}
            @endif
```

But the problem is that at the link

url:'{{url(app('admin').'/department_news/check/parent')}}',

It's getting me error and didn't work and show me the sub category [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvi2i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg4l2.png)

Is that error is becuase of confilct with the Jquery ?

Comment: 500 error is something wrong to your controller. Please look what controller returned to you there into your console. (error message from your controller)

Comment: Yeah, I dont know whats that, I use firebug similar to inbuild console. YOu can also find out the errors in your controller. I can find out the errors from my controller and then correct those errors whenever i get 500

Comment: You should look to laravel.log in <pathtoyourproject>/storage/logs/laravel.log
This file contains errors you need to read

Comment: Go under network tab, click XHR and click your error. The error message should be there

Comment: Can you show the route for this method?

Comment: I have solved the problem , thank you . It was because the wrong name of the model !